# Let user force stop a loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making an app that uses tkinter for interface
the interface has two buttons, one that says 'calculate' and one that says 'stop'.
the Calculate button fires a calculate() which has a recursive call to itself, which makes it either an infinite loop, or a very deep loop. I want the user to be able to be able to make the calculation stop throw the button 'stop'.

```
def init():
    btnCalculate = Button(myframe, text="Caculate", command= Calculate, width=10)
    btnStop = Button(myframe, text="Stop", command= Stop, width=10)
    btnCalculate.place(x=0, y=0)
    btnStop.place(x=100, y=0)

def Calculate():
    Calculate(para)

def Calculate(para):
    # do some stuff
    # check condition
    if condition:
        Calculate(para)

def Stop():
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion blocks event loops that a GUI must use to do its work. So here is a modification of what you have that uses event scheduling to do what you want. To simulate recursion, I repeatedly put a call to the Calculate method on the event stack for processing. You can change the frequency from 1000 (milliseconds) to whatever you need.

```
from tkinter import *

stop = False

def init():
    btnCalculate = Button(myframe, text="Calculate", command=Calculate, width=10)
    btnStop = Button(myframe, text="Stop", command= Stop, width=10)
    btnCalculate.pack()
    btnStop.pack()

#def Calculate():
#    Calculate(para)

def Calculate(*args):
    global stop
    # do some stuff
    # check condition
    if not stop:
        print("Calculating...")
        root.after(1000, lambda a=args: Calculate(a))

def Stop():
    global stop
    print('Stopping')
    stop = True

root = Tk()
myframe = Frame(root)
myframe.pack()
init()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how do you pass multiple arguments instead of just one ?

Comment: Separate with a comma. Assuming you're referring to the lambda function. So if you need to pass 2 parameters:  `root.after(1000, lambda a=args, xy='string': Calculate(a,xy))`

Comment: this kinda works, however, the more deep this recursion goes, the less the interval (which is supposed to be 1000) decreases. it reaches a depth where the interval is so small that the gui blocks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "the gui blocks". Are you decreasing the milliseconds delay in the `after` statement? The GUI won't block. What actually happens is that the calculation takes whatever time it needs, then the even loop reschedules the Calculate to occur *delay* milliseconds in the future.

Comment: I think I know why, it is because one Calculate function will call more than one recursion, which will cause eventually to be many..

Comment: And so if you need more performance, you may be looking at converting all this to multi-processing to leverage the multiple CPUs on your machine. And with that comes a bit of extra complexity :(

Comment: one Calculate will call like 3 other Caculate(), and they will be all scheduled after 1000 ms, and after that, the 3 will call other 3 which will give us 9 that will fire after the second 1000ms, and so on until it reaches a point we have countless calls. but your answer is great. I will try to find how to make this work